# Apache no longer starts (AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key)

Tags: ssh, apache2

My Apache Server no longer starts. Checking the log shows that:

```
[Fri Apr 24 18:05:01.342667 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 21220] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key  
[Fri Apr 24 18:05:01.342716 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 21220] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch  
[Fri Apr 24 18:05:01.342721 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 21220] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
```

I compared the results of

```
openssl x509 -noout -in zertifikat-pub.pem -modulus
```

and

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -in zertifikat-key.pem -modulus
```

They were the same.

In my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`
you can find following lines:

```
 SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/zertifikat-pub.pem  
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/zertifikat-key.pem
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: See http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=5892, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20325002/2734389

Answer (score 1):

From your Vhost or website on apache the `.crt` file does not match the `.key` file.

I had this problem and had to contact my SSL provider to give me the private key file.

This can happen when you make a CSR online and had previously made a CSR server-side.

Hope that helps you.

(To prevent the start failure set your website to http port 80) during your debugging.